# Faster way to check whether a set of $3 \times 3$ matrices is the subspace of some vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, matrix-equations

Is the following subset of the vector space $V=Mat_{3,3}(\mathbb{R})$ are subspaces of $V?$ $\\$

The $3\times 3$ matrices such that the vector $A$
\begin{align}
A\begin{bmatrix}
           7 \\
           6 \\
           8 \\
         \end{bmatrix}
 = \begin{bmatrix} 
0\\
 0\\ 
0\\
 \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

---

I notice that this is essentially a homogenous system of linear equations $A\underline{v}=\underline{0}$, but am not sure how I can use this to do something. Instead, I have just been trying to think of counterexamples that don't satisfy the subspace criterion:
\begin{align} \text{If } \emptyset \neq X \subseteq V,\text{ then } X\leq V \iff X \text{ closed under vector addition and scalar multiplication (subspace criterion)}. 
\end{align}

but it will take so long to consider individual examples of A that satisfy the condition $Av=0$ and then trying to find a counterexample that fails the subspace criterion. Furthermore, how will I even know when I've exhausted enough options?

Answer (score 2):

Let $v\in \mathbb{R}^3$ be a fixed vector.

Then it is easy to check that $A\mapsto Av$ is a linear map from $M_{3\times 3}(\mathbb{R})$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$. The set you describe is the kernel (or null space) of this map, so from general principles is a subspace.

Comment: Thank you! This almost feels like I'm cheating though :)

Answer (score 1):

Let $v = \pmatrix{7\cr 6\cr 8}$. You want to show that
$$
V = \{A \in M_3({\bf R}) \mid Av =0\}
$$
is a vector subspace of $M_3({\bf R})$.
This is proven by showing that for all $A,B\in V$, and all $\lambda \in {\bf R}$, $\lambda A + B \in V$.
And indeed if $Av=0$, $Bv=0$, then by definition of the sum of matrices, $$(\lambda A+B) v = \lambda A v + B v = 0.$$

Comment: Thank you! So, if I am interpreting this correctly, this also means that the value of $v$ does not matter at all? i.e., this is true $\forall v \in V$, and $v$ could as well have been something like \begin{bmatrix} 99\\ 232323\\ 123123123\\ \end{bmatrix}

Comment: Yes. This works for all vectors $v$. There is nothing special about the vector $(7,6,8)$.